# Displaying Both VisualCollection and UIElements

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, uielement, drawingvisual

I'm using a VisualCollection to display custom DrawingVisuals on a Canvas in WPF, and I also need the canvas to display a couple of UIElements. The problem is that the canvas seems to ignore its regular children when using a VisualCollection. The UIElements don't appear when placed in the VC either.

I want the UIElements to be rendered above the DrawingVisuals, so I cannot (?) place the DVs in an AdornerLayer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I sort of found a solution.

I simply create a new FrameworkElement that hosts all the DrawingVisuals through a VisualCollection, and add this host to the canvas as a regular child.